# How to calculate distance travelled from speed and time (not from location points) :Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Can anyone help in this. I want to calculate total distance travelled in a trip from Speed and Time. I can able to get result when distance not below maximum distance but when drops to below maximum distance travelled, the maximum distance is not adding to distance travelled below maximum distance. When speed is reduced to below maximum level distance value also is reducing, actually this need to be added to maximum distance.

**For example:** Speed = 60KM/HR, Time = 300SEC then Distance = 18KM But when speed reduced to 40KM/HR and Total time is 450SEC then Total distance needs to be added to 18KM + (40 * 150 = 6KM) = 24KM but when speed reduced to 40KM/HR the Total distance traveled also reducing to below 18KM.
Here 18KM is the maximum value from ***tripDistMax*** and this value needs to be added to variable speed(min/max level).

Hope you understand my problem and looking for a solution.

> Below is the code.

```java
double tripDistMax = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String tripDistance = tripDistanceCalculation();
    tvTripDistance.setText(tripDistance + " KM");
}

private String tripDistanceCalculation() {
    double distance = 0;
    distance = Double.parseDouble(tvTripDistance.getText().toString());
    String duration = time.getText().toString().trim();
    String split[] = duration.split(":");
    if (split.length == 3) {
        String mainSpeedString = tvSpeed.getText().toString().trim();
        int mainSpeed = Integer.parseInt(mainSpeedString);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        totalSeconds = seconds + (minute * 60) + (hour * 60 * 60);
        if (tripDistMax <= distance) {
            tripDistMax = distance;
        }
        distance = (float) ((mainSpeed * totalSeconds) + tripDistMax) / 1000; //Dist=SpeedxTime
        return new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(distance) + "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First off, the calculation for distance in your question is incorrect. 60 km/h for 300 seconds is not 18km, but 5km. convert your speed to m/s (divide by 3.6) or convert your seconds to hours, and drop the /1000

Comment: Yeah, your example should make 5km over 300s and 1.666...km over 150s. Which would add up to 6.666km.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that code snippet is that you are calling this function once in the onCreate lifecycle hook. This means this component can't remember any of the previous calculations, since it was only just created when the function is called again.

You will need some object to survive the lifecycle, or better yet a way to store previous values. Then you can have your function read previous data, and add to it.